# Should app delete tasks before deleting tasklists

Tags: google-api

I am developing an android app to manage Google Tasks using the Google Tasks API.  When deleting a tasklist that contains tasks, should I delete the existing tasks before deleting their parent tasklist?  Or does deleting the parent tasklist automatically clean up the child tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the tasklist. All [task methods](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/) require a tasklist so once you delete the tasklist they will be useless.